# how to get the data according to the data entered in the query string in golang?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm retrieving the data from the collection in mongodb matches to the data enter in the query string using golang.

There are two cases

**case 1**

Suppose if user search the single field like `first_name`, `last_name` etc. Then the data will be retrieve by hitting the url `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customer?keyword=puneet`

**case 2**

In case 2 suppose we have the two fields in collection of mongodb for example `first_name : puneet`, `last_name : jindal`,etc. If the user will enter the two fields in the query string `first_name` and `last_name`

Example hitting the url like `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customer?keyword=puneet%20kumar` then there is no data retrieval.

I have tried the following  code for this. But not success

Struct for this is:

```
type Customer struct {
  Id          int    `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
  Name        string `json:"name" bson:"name"`
  FirstName   string `json:"first_name" bson:"first_name"`
  LastName    string `json:"last_name" bson:"last_name"`
  Email       string `json:"email" bson:"email"`
  PhoneNumber string `json:"phone_number" bson:"phone_number"`
}
```

Function for retrieving the data:

```
func GetCustomers(c *gin.Context) {
value:= c.Query("keyword")
fmt.Println(value)
response := ResponseControllerList{}
conditions := bson.M{"$or": []bson.M{
    bson.M{"first_name": bson.RegEx{".*" + value, "i"}},
    bson.M{"last_name": bson.RegEx{".*" + value, "i"}},
    bson.M{"email": bson.RegEx{".*" + value, "i"}},
    bson.M{"phone_number": bson.RegEx{".*" + value, "i"}},
}}
data, err := models.GetCustomerListing(conditions)
if err != nil {
    response = ResponseControllerList{
        config.FailureCode,
        config.FailureFlag,
        config.FailureMsg,
        nil,
        nil,
    }
} else {
    response = ResponseControllerList{
        config.SuccessFlag,
        config.SuccessFlag,
        config.SuccessMsg,
        data,
        nil,
    }
}
GetResponseList(c, response)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the solution

```
value:= c.Query("keyword")
fmt.Println(value)
response := ResponseControllerList{}
name := strings.Replace(value, " ", "|", -1)
conditions := bson.M{"$or": []bson.M{
    bson.M{"first_name":bson.RegEx{"(?i).*"+name+".*", "i"} },
    bson.M{"last_name": bson.RegEx{ "(?i).*"+name+".*", "i"} },
    bson.M{"email": bson.RegEx{".*" + value, "i"}},
    bson.M{"phone_number": bson.RegEx{".*" + value, "i"}},
}}
```

change in the query